# How to find an exact string on contacts either on Google or Samsung Contacts

Tags: google-contacts

I just migrated from Apple to Android and transferred all of my contacts.  Each one of my clients is entered as a contact and under the notes section of the contacts I enter the date when I talked to them and I also enter the date on when I need to contact them again, the dates are entered as a string with no spaces, for example today's date would be entered as February3,2021.  Every day I see who I need to call by just entering the date string into search on my contacts App., for example, tomorrow, I will enter February4,2021 and I will see the names of the people who I need to speak to.

Now that I am on Android I do the same thing but when I enter February2,2021 I am also shown February20,2021, February21,2021..... February29,2021.

I need to find a way to search for an exact string to solve my problem, I tried entering the string under " " and that doesn't work and I have not yet found a way to do this.

I would appreciate your help.